# Weighted random choice using a string

Tags: probability, statistics, computer-science

I have a weighted hash -

```
  CHOICES : PROBABILITY

  choice_a: 0.2
  choice_b: 0.7
  choice_c: 0.1
```

Given a string of arbitrary length, say `foobar`, how do I map it to one of these choices with their respective probabilities, and make the selection reproducible?

Say, if string `foobar` maps to `choice_a` the first time around, it should do so consistently for all subsequent calls.

The string can be assumed to be alphanumeric if that helps.

### A naive approach

One can sum up the numerical value of each character (A = 1, B= 2 ...) and then take a mod with the number of choices.

`foobar` => (6 + 15 + 15 + 2 + 1 + 18) =  57

57 % 3 = 0 (choice_a)

The problem with this is, the probabilities are divided equally between the choices.

Comment: Assumming you already have a function that's not "reproducible", you could just memoise it.

Comment: @NealFultz I wanted to avoid storing results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a hash function that maps strings uniformly into the set $\{0,1,\dots,N-1\}$, you can then map this to your distribution by taking $0\leq n\leq N-1$ to:

- Choice A if $0\leq n/N < 0.2$
- Choice B if $0.2\leq n/N < 0.2+0.7$
- Choice C if $0.2+0.7\leq n/N < 1$

This will be an exact mapping if $N$ is a multiple of $10$, and the error will be small for large $N$: the total variation distance is at most $2/N$.
This is a special case of [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), i.e. inverting a cumulative distribution function.

The uniform distribution is always an assumption. An omniscient adversary can always choose inputs to give your hash table worst-case behaviour. In practice, a good choice of string hash function is "SipHash". See here for more discussion of various hash functions: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed/316350#316350.

Comment: Funny that I arrived at a similar solution a while after posting this question. Now I know the mathematical term for this :)